# How to call api before close App in Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I would like to know which is the best way to call an API right before we closing browser, reload, refresh.
I want to save some data to firebase when user close app/ refresh page to know their behavior.
I have tried `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", callback)` and `beforeDestroy` lifeCycle but it seems this doesn't work as expected.
I have checked the function call api has no problem.
I guess the problem is calling api need time api return data while the action closing browser/refresh/reload will happen immediately. So the api call doesn't have enough time to execute.

Nuxt version 2.15.8
Vue version 2.7.10

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Page Firebase</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    async callBack() {
      // call api here
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.callBack);
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    this.callBack();
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Tried with `async beforeDestroy` and `await this.callBack()`? I'm not sure that this is even feasible. Interesting question.

Comment: Yes I tried. But no luck. Thank you.